# I've got a system of ODEs which depends on a parameter $\alpha$, but the solution won't be plotted

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, parameters

```
funkcja[\[Alpha]_] := Module[{rozw},rozw = NDSolve[{-x2[t]-x3[t] == x1'[t],x1[t]==x2'[t],-\[Alpha]*((x1[t])^2+(x2[t])^2)-x3[t]+x1[t]*x3[t]==x3'[t], x1[0]==0, x2[0]==0,x3[0]==0}, {x1[t], x2[t],x3[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, MaxSteps -> 100000];Show[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t],x3[t]} /. rozw], {t, 0, 20}]]];

Manipulate[funkcja[\[Alpha]],{{\[Alpha],-1},-5,5}]
```

It plots nothing:

[image]

This shouldn't be the case.

I don't see my mistake, the code is simple. I solve what I have in NDSolve, then I plot this with ParametricPlot3D. But because this depends on $\alpha$, I must put this everything together inside of Manipulate, where I can change my value for $\alpha$.

So it should work, as similar things worked in the past for me. But it doesn't work here. If I dummy test NDSolve for $\alpha = 1$, it just shows a straight line for the solution of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. So although NDSolve doesn't show me an error message, it still gives me a wrong solution?

Comment: Always check the intermediate results first if something isn't working. I checked the result of `NDSolve` for various values of $\alpha$, and the functions being returned are uniformly constant-zero. Perhaps check your equations to see if you've entered them correctly. This is why nothing is showing up, because the parametric plot isn't making a curve but a single point.

Comment: @march So you suggest that something might be wrong with the actual functions I've used here? I also get uniform constant-zero solutions for x1, x2 and x3.

Comment: Your initial conditions are that each value of x1 x2 x3 are all zero, which makes the solution to the differential equation zero because the equations are homogeneous. Try `x1 == 0.1` and trying again. (In that case, I also suggest adding the option `BoxRatios -> 1` in the call to `ParametricPlot3D`). Also, you don't need the `Show`.

Comment: @march Yes! it worked! My Prof said that we should take "something slightly higher than 0" actually, now I remember it. Thanks a lot. Just a small question: How can I make Manipulate show me the value of $\alpha$ which is currently "used"?

Comment: Add `PlotLabel -> "\[Alpha] = " <> ToString[\[Alpha]]` to the `ParametricPlot3D` call.

Comment: In the `Manipulate` change the iterator to the form `{{α, -1}, -5, 5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}` to see the value of `α`